# Best ways to extract data from a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I have a `List[List[str]]`, where I have these strings:

```
UGLY_DATA = [
             ['4', 'Total=64  (1)=10;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;'],
             ['1', 'Total=16  (1)=16;']
            ]
```

and I need to sort them in the following way:

```
[[12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], [16.0]]
```

I've been trying using `for` loops with `.strip()`, `.split()`, but haven't been successful, any idea how can sort it in the proper way? I'm not allowed to use modules

Edit:

I'm rewriting this question; so I have a `List[list]`:

```
[[4, 'Total=64  (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;'], [1, 'Total=16  (1)=16;']]
```

I'm trying to extract data from the `str` in `[0][1]` and `[1][1]`: and return a list in the following way:

```
[[12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], [16.0]]
```

That means that I need to remove `Total=x` and `(x)=` (x can be any number from the examples) from each `str`.

Comment: (hello there!) Do you mean extract? sort has a different meaning. And please paste a full example. (do not include ...)

Comment: What exactly is the sorting key, `Total` or `(1)` through `(4)`. Or do just need to extract/convert the data?

Comment: Need to remove `Total= , (x)`  and only leave the numbers after parenthesis as `float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track using 'split', though regular expressions may be more robust. Assuming your data is consistent:

EDIT: Per your comment that you want to return a list of floats:

```
UGLY_DATA = [
         ['4', 'Total=64  (1)=10;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;'],
         ['1', 'Total=16  (1)=16;']
        ]


def getNumerics(row):
  relevant_element = row[1]
  # split after '=' and remove Total=64
  split = relevant_element.split("=")[2:] # ['10;(2)', '19;(3)', '21;(4)', '12;']
  # for each item in list: get text before ';' and convert to float
  cleaned = [float(x.split(";")[0]) for x in split]
  return cleaned


# return a new list containing lists of floats
cleaned_data = [getNumerics(row) for row in UGLY_DATA]
print(cleaned_data) # [[10.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0], [16.0]]
```

Comment: Yeah I'm supposed to remove `Total= ` and `(x number)`, leaving only the number after the `=`. So for `'Total=60.4 (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;'` I should return a list `[12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0]`

Comment: I misunderstood you, I thought only the total was relevant. I'll take a look at modifying my answer

Comment: No man, it was my bad I have edited the question so is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to extract those values, you can do:

```
import re

# util function to get the string from an inner list
get_s = lambda lst: next(x for x in lst if isinstance(x, str) and x.startswith('Total='))

# util to turn that string into a list of floats
nums = lambda s: list(map(float, re.findall(r'\(\d+\)=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', s)))

clean_data = [nums(get_s(x)) for x in UGLY_DATA]
# [[12.0, 19.0, 21.0, 12.0]
#  [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2]
#  [16.0]]
```

Or without the `re` module, using just `str.split`:

```
nums = lambda s: list(map(float, (f.split('=')[1] for f in s.split()[1].split(';')[:-1])))
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use modules :(

Comment: @SBernal I added a versoin of `nums` that doesn't use the `re` module

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is the key:

```
import re

data = [ 4, 'Total=64  (1)=12;(2)=19;(3)=21;(4)=12;',]

s = [re.findall(re.compile('=(\d+);'),da) for da in data if isinstance(da,str)][0]

print(s)
```

Now you need a function that will do that for all the lines :)